# Is $a+b=b+a$ always true in the whole algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

$ab=ba$ is not always true in quaternion calculations.
But how about $a+b=b+a$ ? Is it always true?

Comment: Yes $a+b=b+a$ always by [commutative property of addition](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-sixth-grade-math/cc-6th-factors-and-multiples/properties-of-numbers/a/properties-of-addition). It is a axion so it has no proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commutativity of addition is one of the axioms for the quaternions so it's always true.

That commutativity is assumed for every algebra. Only the multiplication may not be commutative.